# Pandas - Concatenate rows that are truncated

Tags: python, pandas

I found a db online that contains for a series of anonymous users their degrees and the inverse sequence in which they completed them (last degree first).
For each user, I have:

- Their UserID
- The inverse sequence
- The degree title

Basically my dataframe looks like this:

| User_ID | Sequence | Degree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | MSc in Civil |
| 123 | 1 | Engineering |
| 123 | 2 | BSc in Engineering |

As you can see, my issue is that at times degree titles are truncated and split into two separate rows (User 123 has a MSc in Civil Engineering - notice the same value in sequence).

Ideally, my dataframe should look like this:

| User_ID | Sequence | Degree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | MSc in Civil Engineering |
| 123 | 2 | BSc in Engineering |

I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I will be happy to provide any more insight that may be needed for assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate):

```
df.groupby(['User_ID', 'Sequence'], as_index=False).aggregate(' '.join)
```

```
   User_ID  Sequence                    Degree
0      123         1  MSc in Civil Engineering
1      123         2        BSc in Engineering
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'User_ID': [123, 123, 123],
    'Sequence': [1, 1, 2],
    'Degree': ['MSc in Civil', 'Engineering', 'BSc in Engineering']
})
df = df.groupby(['User_ID', 'Sequence'], as_index=False).aggregate(' '.join)
print(df)
```

Comment: The issue was related to degrees format. Thank you so so much!